# Highchart axis hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

What I am working on it, to change the color of the barchart, when hover y axis. In the chart I have two line and one bar chart and have three y axis for it.

`y axis[0] -- bar chart 
y axis[1] -- line chart 1
y axis[2] -- line chart 2`

when I hover y axis[0], I want to change the color of the barchart respectively.

What I tried

For this process I do not know how to get the axis on which I am hovering. So I am unable to move further.

fiddle
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pLkv/)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [customEvents](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin to attach events to labels. Then you can update fill for each of columns, see demo for first one: http://jsfiddle.net/6pLkv/5/

When you use `axis.series`, then in series array you have onyl series conected to that axis. You don't have to worry about indexes etc.

```
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +' mm';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                },
                events: {
                    mouseover: function () {
                        this.axis.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
                            fill: 'red' 
                        });
                    },
                    mouseout: function() {
                        this.axis.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
                            fill: 'blue' 
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Hi Pawel Fus,I tried to apply it for the line chart(temperate), but the change of color is applying for the point alone i.e it only applies for the small diamond and cannot apply to the whole line. Instead of applying color to data like data[0],data[1]. Is there a way to apply to all the data related to the axis.

Comment: Sure, to apply color for each of markers, just loop over all of points. To change line color use that solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6pLkv/5/

Comment: Thanks Pawel,it worked and is there a way to change the chart color when we move the mouse over the axis title too, i tried to call the mouseout and mouseover function in title but it is no use.

Comment: At this moment click event on the title is not available, but it is requested here: https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events/issues/2 so we will add it in the nearest future.

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at this there seems to be no easy way!

However you can target a particular series like this:

```
axisCount = 3;
seriesIWant = 1;
$(document).on('mouseover', '.highcharts-axis:eq(' + (axisCount - 1) + '), .highcharts-axis-labels:eq(' + (axisCount - 1) + ') ', function () {
    console.log('mouseover');
    $('.highcharts-series:nth-child(' + seriesIWant + ') rect').each(
    function (i, element) {
        $(element).css('fill', '#000');
    });
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.highcharts-axis:eq(' + (axisCount - 1) + '), .highcharts-axis-labels:eq(' + (axisCount - 1) + ')', function () {
    $('.highcharts-series:nth-child(' + seriesIWant + ') rect').each(
    function (i, element) {
        $(element).css('fill', '#4572A7');
    });
});
```

`axisCount` is 1-based and here is reflecting the order of the axis you added in the JS (1 = x-axis, 2 = y-axis-1 (temperature) and 3 = y-axis-2 (Rainfall) ). 
`seriesIWant` is 1-based on the order of the series' being added in the JS, this specifies the "chart" of that series.  So hence here `1` is your barchart.  It seems to work ok. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/6pLkv/4/

Comment: Hi Rob, what i want is when we hover over the Rainfall(y axis), the bar chart should change color in the chart

Comment: Updated answer and demo.